# Doubt regarding dual channel MOSFET datasheet

Tags: mosfet, datasheet

I came across a dual channel MOSFET [link for dual channel MOSFET](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/on-semiconductor/NTJD4401NT1G/NTJD4401NT1GOSTR-ND/661400)

But I am confused about the drain current of 0.63A. Do they mean drain current of each channel is 0.63A or for both channels combined?

Comment: This NTJD440 isn't a *dual channel* MOSFET, it is a *dual N-channel* MOSFET meaning 2 NMOSFETs in one package.

Answer (score 1):

This NTJD440 is a *dual N-channel* MOSFET meaning 2 NMOSFETs in one package.

The listed ratings are for **ONE** MOSFET. It would be very confusing of the combined rating was listed. Also note how in the drawing there is **no connection** between the two devices:

[image]

that generally means you can treat them as if each is a separate device.

It is listed that the maximum \$I_D\$ is 0.63 A. Nowhere does it state that this is the combined current (it would/should state that as: \$I_D = I_{D1} + I_{D2}\$ or similar).

So the 0.63 A is **per device**.